# Jamaican citizen, Indian husband; travelling to Jamaica on one-way tickets

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, jamaican-citizens

I am a Jamaican citizen. My husband is an Indian citizen. I am planning on  buying a one-way ticket for the both of us, because once in the country I will be applying for Unconditional Landing status for him. Will arriving on a one-way ticket be a problem for my husband at immigration, because he wouldn't have an onwards ticket?

Comment: This http://www.congenjamaica-ny.org/visas/requirements-2/ indicates that your husband needs a Spouse entry visa if he intends to remain in Jamaica.

Comment: For the love of everything use some punctuation!